# ES6: For Classes to have a Single Definition for Each Method

Tags: node.js, oop, ecmascript-6, lint

Recently, after a vcs merge gone wrong, we discovered that ES6 classes (at least in NodeJS) allow you to have a method defined twice.  i.e. the below program runs without complaint.

```
class Test {
  foo() {
    console.log("first one")
  }

  foo() {
    console.log("second one")
  }
}
const test = new Test;
test.foo()
```

In our real world example the two method definitions were pretty far apart in the source file and it had us stumped for a while. Is there a way to force ES6 classes in NodeJS to *not* allow this?  Is there a flag we can run `node` with that will not allow this, or maybe an es-lint rule?  Or some third thing I'm not thinking of?

We'd basically like something that will prevent our program from running if there's a single class with two methods defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint provides the [no-dupe-class-members](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-dupe-class-members) rule to detect this type of issue. This is part of the `eslint:recommended` config, so if you're not already getting an error, you've most likely not enabled that. Enabling the specific rule is easy if that's the route you want to take, but I'd really consider enabling `eslint:recommended` in general so that you're maintaining less yourself. You can always turn off warnings that `eslint:recommended` activates that you don't like, but then at least you don't have to maintain a full list of opt-in plugins yourself, and instead maintain a list of things to opt *out* of instead.